# swift 3 filtering core data search results

Tags: swift, nspredicate

I am trying to see why when I type in either a meal name or type of meal it doesn't really search properly. Is there anything wrong with what I have going on here?

**UPDATED WITH FILTERED OBJECTS**

```
  var searchPredicate: NSPredicate?
  var filteredObjects : [MealStats]? = nil

  func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController){

    if let searchText = self.resultSearchController.searchBar.text {
        searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "mealname CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR mealtype CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText, searchText)

        filteredObjects = self.fetchedResultController.fetchedObjects?.filter() {

            return self.searchPredicate!.evaluate(with: $0)
            } as [MealStats]?

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
   }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let mealstats = fetchedResultController.object(at: indexPath)

        if searchPredicate == nil
        {           
          self.configureCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
          return cell
        } else {
          cell.textLabel?.text = mealstats.mealtype
          cell.detailTextLabel!.text = mealstats.mealname

          return cell

        }
    }
```

Comment: Do `filterObjects` contains the rights values? Do you read after `filteredObjects` in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: I updated with filtered objects. Not sure if I done that correctly

Comment: This is very cumbersome. Set the `predicate` property of `fetchedResultController` accordingly and re-fetch the data.

Comment: vadian - How I had the predicate is completely wrong? Im not sure about the correct format as to setting the predicate.